# populate AutoCompleteTextView with SQlite database column

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, return, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to figure out how to load information from a table in my SQLite database into an AutoCompleteTextView. I've searched through hundreds of posts and websites. All of the posts that seemed helpful have different methods of creating tables to the one I have used, and so the syntax for using the simple cursor adapter isn't making any sense to me.

My program allows a user to enter food items into a database. From a different section of this program, I want the users to be able to add these food items into their own little food storage - I have already created the XML file for this. However, I don't have a clue how to return the FoodItems 'Name' column into my `AutoCompleteTextView` - I've read something about an Array Adapter but quite frankly I have no idea what I'm doing.

I've already created the table and there is data in the database. I'll only show the code relevant to my problem so as not to overload you. The code used for writing the database is:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ChangeMe.db";
public static final String TABLE_CREATE_FOODS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FoodItems (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, Name TEXT, Category TEXT, Calorie NUMERIC, Fat NUMERIC, Carbohydrate NUMERIC)";
```

Then, I have a method to set these food items:

```
public long SetFoodItems(String name, String category, Float calorie, Float fat, Float carbohydrate) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM FoodItems";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("Name", name);
    values.put("Category", category);
    values.put("Calorie", calorie);
    values.put("Fat", fat);
    values.put("Carbohydrate", carbohydrate);

    long id = db.insert("FoodItems", null, values);
    return id;
}
```

I've also made a cursor to obtain all of the records from the FoodItems table:

```
public Cursor ObtainFoodItems()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Query = "SELECT Name FROM FoodItems";
    Cursor CR = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

    return CR;
}
```

So, can anyone tell me how I return this cursor into an autoCompleteTextView? Please bear in mind that I am a complete newbie to Java (and coding in general), so simplified suggestions would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: The best example I could find was [HERE](http://www.androidcode.ninja/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database/), however he calls on MyObject to populate his autoTextView and loads data manually, which I don't need to do as my user will be responsible for all data entry.

The section of code that I don't understand from that link is:

```
// this function is used in CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java
public String[] getItemsFromDb(String searchTerm){

    // add items on the array dynamically
    List<MyObject> products = databaseH.read(searchTerm);
    int rowCount = products.size();

    String[] item = new String[rowCount];
    int x = 0;

    for (MyObject record : products) {

        item[x] = record.objectName;
        x++;
    }

    return item;
}
```

This is mainly because his function to create the table is completely different to mine:

```
// creating table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "";

    sql += "CREATE TABLE " + tableName;
    sql += " ( ";
    sql += fieldObjectId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ";
    sql += fieldObjectName + " TEXT ";
    sql += " ) ";

    db.execSQL(sql);

}
```

---

So this is my code where I implement an AutoCompleteTextView, call the method to fetch the data from the SQLite db and loop through the records, and set the Array Adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView (I think). However something is wrong, I feel as though I've missed something because it's not doing anything.

```
public class AddToPantry extends AppCompatActivity {
AutoCompleteTextView foodItemsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_pantry);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.editCategory);
    String[] items = new String[]{"Dairy", "Grain", "Vegetable", "Fruit", "Meat" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner dropdownLoc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.editLocation);
    String[] itemsLoc = new String[]{"Cupboard", "Fridge", "Freezer" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLoc = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemsLoc);
    dropdownLoc.setAdapter(adapterLoc);

    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveIngredient);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddItemToPantry();
        }
    });

    //Creates the array
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

    //Implements AutoCompleteTextView
    foodItemsList = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoFoodName);

    //Calls method from DH to get all food items
    DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor cr = dbh.ObtainFoodItems();
    cr.moveToFirst();

    while (cr.moveToNext()) {
        cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Name"));
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> foodItemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, array);

    foodItemsList.setAdapter(foodItemAdapter);
}
```

Comment: "the syntax for using the simple cursor adapter isn't making any sense to me" -- if you edit your question to include what syntax you don't understand, maybe we could explain it to you. Also providing links to what you've looked at helps prevent others from marking this as a possible duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are using the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) class, the simplest implementation would be to:

1. Implement an AutoCompleteTextView
2. Fetch Data from your db and loop to put all the values in an Array
3. Create an ArrayAdapter and attach it to your AutoCompleteTextView.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

First Create an `array`

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayLIst<>();
```

Inside the method you've read the cursor, loop through it and add those item to `array`

```
while (CR.moveToNext()) {
        CR.getString(CR.getColumnIndex('NAME'));
    }
```

Finally Set the adapter to AutoCompleteTextView like this,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, array);
autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work; I commented below my attempt at inserting your suggestions as I couldn't fit the entire code as a response to your answer. Could you tell me if I'm missing anything please?

Comment: Have logged your variable `CR` and confirmed if it has proper data ?